# How to dynamically host any domain w/o creating folders specifically for it?

Tags: apache-httpd

Suppose a domain name has been pointed to my server's IP address..

soon as the domain name comes to me..

i want apache to execute...

```
 python_script domain.tld
```

or perhaps..

```
 bash_script domain.tld
```

if the incoming domain looks like this:

```
domain.tld/test
```

then..

```
 bash_script domain.tld/test
```

should be executed.

from within the bash script i can run calculations and decide what to display.

perhaps things do not work this way due to security concerns but security is not my concern. just would like to test it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A default install of `apache` will serve all URLs pointing to it if no Virtual Hosts have been defined.  Therefore you do not need to do anything extra to get `apache` to respond.

The scripts can be ran as CGI scripts by placing them in `/var/www/cgi-bin` and making sure that they are executable with `chmod 0755 <script name>`.

For example, if you create `/var/www/cgi-bin/test.sh` as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<pre>"
env
echo "</pre>
```

then navigate to your browser at: `http://<server name or IP>/cgi-bin/test.sh`, you should see something similar to:

```
SERVER_SIGNATURE=
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at testing.lo Port 80

HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
SERVER_PORT=80
HTTP_HOST=testing.lo
DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/var/www/cgi-bin/test.sh
REQUEST_URI=/cgi-bin/test.sh
SCRIPT_NAME=/cgi-bin/test.sh
HTTP_CONNECTION=keep-alive
REMOTE_PORT=43964
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
PWD=/var/www/cgi-bin
SERVER_ADMIN=root@localhost
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE=en-gb,en;q=0.5
HTTP_ACCEPT=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
REMOTE_ADDR=192.168.122.1
SHLVL=1
SERVER_NAME=testing.lo
SERVER_SOFTWARE=Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
QUERY_STRING=
SERVER_ADDR=192.168.122.40
GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL=max-age=0
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING=gzip, deflate
REQUEST_METHOD=GET
_=/bin/env
```

As you can see `HTTP_HOST` is the URL of the server (`testing.lo` in this instance) which you can then use in your script.

However, this isn't exactly as you requested as you have `/cgi-bin/test.sh` in the URL.  To fix this, you need to redirect.  The simplest way would be to enable the `.htaccess` file and configure it.

In `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` find the line `<Directory "/var/www/html">` and scroll down a few lines until you see a line that starts `AllowOverride`. Make sure it is set to `All`.  You should have:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
...
...
AllowOverride All
...
...
</Directory>
```

Now create a file `/var/www/html/.htaccess` and add the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) /cgi-bin/test.sh/$1 [L]
```

Restart `apache`:

```
service httpd restart
```

Point your browser at the server's URL: `http://<server name or IP>`.

You should see similar results to before, but without having to append the script path to the URL.  Also notice that there are environment variables that tell you what URL was entered so that your script can use them.

`HTTP_HOST` is the name of the server.

`PATH_INFO` is the path appended to the server. (`test` if you enter `http://<server name or IP>/test` in your browser).

In your `bash` script, you simply need to use these variables instead of parsing the script's arguments as your question suggested.

The script doesn't have to be `bash` though.  Use any language you wish as long as it can access the environment variables passed to it.